# how to jump or switch month and year from date picker in calendar

Tags: react-native

when set date from date picker in calendar then date is update but month and year not jump to switch in calendar

I have onDateChange function and set in calendar and create ref of calendar but not fix my issue, but calendar ref not accept any other logic to set this issue,